# Evaluating limits; direct substitution all at once or one by one?

Tags: limits

When evaluating limits by direct substitution, is it necessary to give the limiting value to all the variables at the same time, or is it okay to simplify smaller expressions in the overall function by substituting the variable with the value one by one?

For an (impractical) example, $\frac{(e^{(x+2)ln4})^\frac{\lfloor x+1\rfloor}{4}-16}{4^x - 16}$. This is the expression as the function approaches 2 from the left. On simplifying it, you get $\frac{2^{\frac{\lfloor x+1 \rfloor (x+2)}{2}}}{2^{2x}-16}$. One solution from the internet broke down the $\lfloor x+1\rfloor$ into 2, but kept everything else the same.

How does that work out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a property of the floor function. Note that for $x \in [1,2)$, $\lfloor x+1 \rfloor = 2$. Hence

$$\frac{2^{\frac{\lfloor x+1 \rfloor (x+2)}{2}}}{2^{2x}-16} = \frac{2^{\frac{2 (x+2)}{2}}}{2^{2x}-16}$$

Since we only care about the value of the function near $2^-$, writing

$$\lim_{x \to 2^-}\frac{2^{\frac{\lfloor x+1 \rfloor (x+2)}{2}}}{2^{2x}-16} = \lim_{x \to 2^-}\frac{2^{\frac{2 (x+2)}{2}}}{2^{2x}-16}$$

is valid. One cannot substitute the limit value of $x$ one by one, e.g.

$$4=\lim_{x \to 2} \frac {x^2-4}{x-2} \ne \lim_{x \to 2}\frac {4-4}{x-2} =0$$

but what we did to your example is not substitution. Another example would be:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac {|x|}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac {-x}{x} = -1$$

since near $0^-$, $|x| = -x$.

Comment: The second one kinda makes sense; you're not actually inputting the number, but applying a property that applies to it. But equating $\lfloor x+1\rfloor$ to 2... really can't be done without substituting the number, can it? So is this only applicable to the absolute value function and floor function? Are there more functions, and do you have any links I can read this up on?

Comment: Both the floor, ceiling and absolute value functions are piecewise, so their definition depends on the interval we are considering. In this case, since the limit is to $2^-$, we consider the interval $(2-\delta, 2)$, where $\delta$ is small. In this case, for $\delta \le 1$ we have $\lfloor x+1\rfloor = 2$ on this interval (which you can technically call a "property" of this function). For some more examples, perhaps see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851187/evaluate-the-limit-of-frac-sin-lfloor-x1-rfloor-lfloor-x1-rfloor-at?rq=1 and some of the related questions there.

Comment: Oh, because $\lfloor x+1 \rfloor$ is going to end up that way not just for the limiting case we're talking about, but also for the space of an entire integer in that direction? So it technically isn't a *limit* that we're calculating. Is that it?

Comment: More or less. The space does not need to be an entire integer, this works as long as there is a nonzero interval where it is identical to another function (in this case, identical to a constant value).